# Inconsistencies with Flickr API Search vs www.flickr.com

Tags: search, photo, flickr

There is a sort of a discrepancy in searching via the API endpoint provided by Flickr and when you actually search in Flickr via their text box search. When searching for certain words like `Jerry Brown` using `flickr.photos.search` I get different set of results when compared to searching directly on **flickr.com**.

There are no additional parameters provided for the API End point apart from the *per_page* and the *page* option, which defaults to `1`.

Comment: What is your API call?  Have you tried Yahoo Query Language (YQL)?

Comment: @Teddy, Its a normal flickr search where in I pass the `search term`, `per_page` and `page` parameters.

Answer (score 5):

This is the reason why it differs

1. Flickr Search (flickr.com) - displays the search results by **relevance**.
2. If **NO Argument** is specified to *sort* in the flickr.photos.search API. Then it defaults to *Recent*

Example

1. http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=cat&f=hp
2. http://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.search

   - Fill in the **text** = cat
             **sort** = relevance
             **per_page** = 1
   - You can verify the result by appropriately constructing the image URL as per `http://farm{farm-id}.static.flickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg`